# Unable to integrate FacebookConnect plugin into Cordova 3

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I am going through README.md file to integrate [FacebookConnect plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect). The README file mentions a com.facebook.LoginActivity class. This file does not exist in https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect. Where can I find it?